# Pokemon type evaluator - follow-up

Tags: java, beginner, swing, lambda, pokemon

I started anew and completely refactored the way I implemented [Pokemon type evaluator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60965/pokemon-type-evaluator).

Also, first use of a lambda expression (Case of using it, but still don't fully grasp how it's working). I'm wondering if this is a bit more complex than it needs to be, but otherwise I think these are some significant improvements.

`Element` enum:

```
public enum Element {
    NONE("None"),
    NORMAL("Normal"),
    FIRE("Fire"),
    WATER("Water"),
    ELECTRIC("Electric"),
    GRASS("Grass"),
    BUG("Bug"),
    POISON("Poison"),
    ICE("Ice"),
    DRAGON("Dragon"),
    FAIRY("Fairy"),
    STEEL("Steel"),
    ROCK("Rock"),
    GROUND("Ground"),
    FIGHTING("Fighting"),
    FLYING("Flying"),
    PSYCHIC("Psychic"),
    DARK("Dark"),
    GHOST("Ghost");

    public final String name;

    Element(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`PokemonType` class:

```
    import java.util.HashMap;

public class PokemonType {
    String name;
    HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers = new HashMap<Element, Double>();
    Element element;

    PokemonType(Builder p) {
        name = p.name; multipliers = p.multipliers; element = p.element;
    }

    static class Builder {
        final String name;
        HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers = new HashMap<Element, Double>();
        Element element;

        public Builder(Element element) {
            this.name = element.name;
            this.element = element;
            // Default values
            for (Element e : Element.values()) {
                multipliers.put(e, 1.0);
            }
        }

        public Builder vulnerableTo(Element... elements) {
            for (Element e : elements) { multipliers.put(e, 2.0); }
            return this;
        }
        public Builder immuneTo(Element... elements) {
            for (Element e : elements) { multipliers.put(e, 0.0); }
            return this;
        }
        public Builder resistantTo(Element... elements) {
            for (Element e : elements) { multipliers.put(e, 0.5); }
            return this;
        }
        public PokemonType generate() { return new PokemonType(this); }
    }
    public HashMap<Element, Double> getMultipliers() {
        return this.multipliers;
    }
}
```

`PokemonTypeChecker` class, which includes `main`:

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

public class PokemonTypeChecker {

    static PokemonType normal = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.NORMAL)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.FIGHTING).immuneTo(Element.GHOST).generate();

    static PokemonType fire = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.FIRE)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.WATER, Element.GROUND, Element.ROCK)
            .resistantTo(Element.FIRE, Element.GRASS, Element.ICE,
                    Element.BUG, Element.STEEL, Element.FAIRY)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType water = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.WATER)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.ELECTRIC, Element.GRASS)
            .resistantTo(Element.FIRE, Element.WATER, Element.ICE, Element.STEEL)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType electric = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.ELECTRIC)
            .resistantTo(Element.ELECTRIC, Element.STEEL, Element.FLYING)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.GROUND).generate();

    static PokemonType grass = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.GRASS)
            .resistantTo(Element.GRASS, Element.WATER, Element.GROUND, Element.ELECTRIC)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.FIRE, Element.ICE,
                    Element.POISON, Element.FLYING, Element.BUG)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType ice = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.ICE)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.FIRE, Element.STEEL, Element.ROCK, Element.FIGHTING)
            .resistantTo(Element.ICE).generate();

    static PokemonType fighting = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.FIGHTING)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.PSYCHIC, Element.FLYING, Element.FAIRY)
            .resistantTo(Element.BUG, Element.ROCK, Element.DARK)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType poison = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.POISON)
            .resistantTo(Element.GRASS, Element.FIGHTING, Element.POISON,
                    Element.BUG, Element.FAIRY)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.GROUND, Element.PSYCHIC).generate();

    static PokemonType ground = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.GROUND)
            .resistantTo(Element.POISON, Element.ROCK)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.WATER, Element.GRASS, Element.ICE)
            .immuneTo(Element.ELECTRIC).generate();

    static PokemonType flying = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.FLYING)
            .resistantTo(Element.GRASS, Element.FIGHTING, Element.BUG)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.ELECTRIC, Element.ICE, Element.ROCK)
            .immuneTo(Element.GROUND).generate();

    static PokemonType psychic = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.PSYCHIC)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.BUG, Element.DARK, Element.GHOST)
            .resistantTo(Element.FIGHTING, Element.PSYCHIC).generate();

    static PokemonType bug = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.BUG)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.FIRE, Element.FLYING, Element.ROCK)
            .resistantTo(Element.GRASS, Element.FIGHTING, Element.GROUND)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType rock = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.ROCK)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.WATER, Element.GRASS, Element.FIGHTING,
                    Element.GROUND, Element.STEEL)
            .resistantTo(Element.NORMAL, Element.FIRE, Element.POISON, Element.FLYING)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType ghost = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.GHOST)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.GHOST, Element.DARK)
            .resistantTo(Element.BUG, Element.POISON)
            .immuneTo(Element.NORMAL, Element.FIGHTING)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType dragon = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.DRAGON)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.ICE, Element.DRAGON, Element.FAIRY)
            .resistantTo(Element.WATER, Element.FIRE, Element.ELECTRIC, Element.GRASS)
            .generate();

    static PokemonType dark = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.DARK)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.FIGHTING, Element.BUG, Element.FAIRY)
            .resistantTo(Element.GHOST, Element.DARK)
            .immuneTo(Element.PSYCHIC).generate();

    static PokemonType steel = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.STEEL)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.FIRE, Element.FIGHTING, Element.GROUND)
            .resistantTo(Element.NORMAL, Element.GRASS, Element.ICE, Element.FLYING,
                    Element.PSYCHIC, Element.BUG, Element.ROCK, Element.DRAGON,
                    Element.STEEL, Element.FAIRY)
            .immuneTo(Element.POISON).generate();

    static PokemonType fairy = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.FAIRY)
            .vulnerableTo(Element.STEEL, Element.POISON)
            .resistantTo(Element.FIGHTING, Element.DARK, Element.BUG)
            .immuneTo(Element.DRAGON).generate();

    static PokemonType none = new PokemonType.Builder(Element.NONE).generate();

    static ArrayList<PokemonType> pokemonTypes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(normal,
            fighting, flying, fire, water, electric, grass, bug, poison, steel, ground,
            rock, ice, dragon, fairy, psychic, dark, ghost, none));

    static JTextField immunities = new JTextField(15),
            resistances = new JTextField(15), vulnerabilities = new JTextField(15);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pokemon Type Checker");
        JPanel selectionPanel = new JPanel(), result = new JPanel();
        result.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 0, 2));

        immunities.setEditable(false);
        resistances.setEditable(false);
        vulnerabilities.setEditable(false);

        result.add(new JLabel("Immune to:"));
        result.add(immunities);
        result.add(new JLabel("Resistant to:"));
        result.add(resistances);
        result.add(new JLabel("Vulnerable to:"));
        result.add(vulnerabilities);

        JComboBox<String> typeList = new JComboBox<String>();
        JComboBox<String> typeList2 = new JComboBox<String>();

        for (Element e : Element.values()) {
            typeList.addItem(e.name);
            typeList2.addItem(e.name);
        }

        typeList.setSelectedItem(Element.NORMAL.name);

        ItemListener typeListener = e -> {
            PokemonType primaryPokemonType = normal, secondaryPokemonType = none;
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                displayAttributes(getPokemonType((String)typeList.getSelectedItem()),
                        getPokemonType((String)typeList2.getSelectedItem())
                );
            }
        };

        typeList.addItemListener(typeListener);
        typeList2.addItemListener(typeListener);

        selectionPanel.add(typeList);
        selectionPanel.add(typeList2);

        frame.add(result, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(selectionPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void displayAttributes(PokemonType primary, PokemonType secondary) {
        if (primary == secondary) { secondary = none; }

        immunities.setText("");
        vulnerabilities.setText("");
        resistances.setText("");
        StringBuilder immuneBuilder = new StringBuilder(""),
                vulnerableBuilder = new StringBuilder(""),
                resistBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

        for(Map.Entry<Element, Double> entry : primary.getMultipliers().entrySet()){
            for(Map.Entry<Element, Double> entry2 : secondary.getMultipliers().entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey() == entry2.getKey()) {

                    if (entry.getValue() * entry2.getValue() == 0.0) {
                        immuneBuilder.append(entry.getKey().name).append(", ");
                    }
                    else if (entry.getValue() * entry2.getValue()  <= 0.5 ) {
                        resistBuilder.append(entry.getKey().name).append(", ");
                    }
                    else if (entry.getValue() * entry2.getValue()  >= 2.0) {
                        vulnerableBuilder.append(entry.getKey().name).append(", ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        finalizeBuilder(immuneBuilder);
        finalizeBuilder(resistBuilder);
        finalizeBuilder(vulnerableBuilder);

        immunities.setText(immuneBuilder.toString());
        vulnerabilities.setText(vulnerableBuilder.toString());
        resistances.setText(resistBuilder.toString());
    }

    public static PokemonType getPokemonType(String name) {
        for (PokemonType p : pokemonTypes) {
            if (p.element.name == name) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return none; // should never be the case
    }
    // To make sure that the field says if nothing applies
    public static StringBuilder finalizeBuilder(StringBuilder sb) {
        if (sb.length() == 0) { sb.append("None."); }
        else {
            // Just to replace the last comma with a period
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
            sb.append('.');
        }
        return sb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the overall design is good, although make the main method create a new PokemonTypeChecker and then move all the stuff currently in the main method to a `run` method or similar - doing logic in the constructor is bad practice, and not writing OO code (i.e. making everything static) is too. You could also perhaps consider JavaFX over swing/awt too.

Comments:

- It seems like Type may be a better name than Element?
- It's good practice to make everything as private as possible, so consider making the Element constructor private.
- Override toString in the enumerated type instead of having to specify a name in the constructor (you could utilise [name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--)).
- It's good practice to make classes that shouldn't be extended final.
- Use the [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) to make it quicker to change the left hand side of a generic class, and faster to write.
- Use the least-specific (but relevant) parent class on the LHS to make it quicker to change and, usually, write (as stated in Effective Java).

Old:

```
HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers = new HashMap<Element, Double>();
```

New:

```
Map<Element, Double> multipliers = new HashMap<>();
```

- Is there a reason you're using JTextFields over a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) or similar? You're preventing them from being edited anyway.
- You might as well initialise empty StringBuilders instead of specifying the empty string literal in the constructor (they're identical).
- If the `return none;` part of the `getPokemonType` method should never happen, then you probably want to throw an unchecked exception there (likely [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)).
- Looks like the you could make use of [Stream#filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) in the `displayAttributes`.

Possibly subjective points I wanted to include regardless:

- Conventionally the method is called "build" rather than generate.
- I prefer Guava's way of [instantiating builders](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#builder%28%29) because then you don't need to type the inner class (`MyBuilder.Builder`) and it's shorter.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, very nice answer you got here! I'm sure you'll feel right at home!

Comment: Ah on the toString suggestion, the Elements each contain images. I just edited them as strings so a reviewer could compile the code. I actually should make a point to learn JavaFX...or at least understand why I should, thank you.

Comment: and now all my visual code is JavaFx, haha. Still need to actually apply FXML more though. Thank you again @Toby

Comment: No problem @Legato - glad to see you are continuing to improve your project :-)